# Vue basics -- use component in other component

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use a Vue component (a header) inside of another component, but it's not rendering it correctly.

My code:

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <header></header>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app'
}
</script>
```

Header.vue:

```
<template>
    <nav class="nav">
         <div class="container">
             <div class="nav-left">
                 <p class="title"></p>
             </div>
         </div>
     </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'header'
}
</script>
```

And, I register my component in main.js, with the file looking like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.component('header', require('./components/Header'))

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

With my very limited understanding this should be like rendering a React `<Header />` in my App, but this is not working that way. What's getting rendered to the DOM is a plain `<header></header>` tag inside of my `#app`, which isn't exactly ideal.

What key point am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: are you sure the ./components/Header is correct? because your code should work. also try adding .vue to end of that path.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. You are right -- it should work if I wasn't stupid enough to name my component `header`, which is an existing HTML tag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot name a component with the name of an [existing HTML tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header). The development version of Vue will warn you of this in the console.

> [Vue warn]: Do not use built-in or reserved HTML elements as component
>   id: header

Rename your `header` component with some other name.

Comment: Awesome, you are right. Thank you -- so many hours lost on this!

Comment: is the name: '' all we have to change? can the filename still include an html-like name? e.g. 'Footer.vue', and also in the import Footer from ./components/Footer do these also have to be renamed? or only in Vue instance name definition

Comment: IME, only the instance name needs to be changed; the component filename can still be whatever you want. For example, I have a Map.vue component, and when declared with `name: 'map'`, I get the Vue warning as Bert described above. Changing it to something else like `name: 'mapComp'` cleared the error. In either case, my app was still functional, but it's better to heed warnings, at the very least to keep exercising semantic HTML markup.